# Changing "add to wishlist" to "add to cart" , functionality and text EVERYWHERE GLOBALLY

Tags: php

What is the best way to change ALL "add to wishlist" in a magento webshop? I want to REPLACE it with "add to cart"

Thanks!

Comment: You want add to cart insted of Wishlist right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take Backup Before that.

**Go to** `app\design\frontend\package\theme\template\catalog\product\view\addto.phtml`

Command this

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
</li>
```

then add this

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Since I had "template masters higlight" module installed  it was located in my frontend/argento/pure/template/tm/highlight/product/grid.phtml :-)

Comment: Changed                                 <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                  with                            <li class="li-wishlist"><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></a></li>
   and it is working like a charm :D